# Look at git blame but also previous git blames of the same line

Tags: git

Many times I look at a line and see the blame for it. Then I get something like "fixed indentation".
I would like to be able to go one commit before that indentation fix, and see the blame for that line again.
Does that make sense? Can I do that somehow, without doing the checkout, blame again manually?

Answer (score 3):

It’s definitely possible. Let’s say the hash of your useless commit is `abcdef1`. Then its parent (previous commit) can be accessed using `abcdef1~1`. So to blame the commit before `abcdef1`, run:

```
git blame abcdef1~1 file.txt
```

Comment: In other words, there is no need to checkout to blame, you can blame starting from any version

Comment: You can use `^` instead of `~1`.

Comment: @hobbs Yes but it has two disadvantages. I rather count previous commits than parents (I find `~2` more useful than `^^`) and `^` is a special character in Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

Blame built in GUI programs often provide an option to blame further starting from the parent of found commit. For example `git gui blame $file` has such item in context menu for a line. What I like even more is "Find origin of this line" command in `gitk` - it's more focused on what I really want to get. Then if necessary I run it again on the older line in the found diff.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question, but it's a general git tip: You shouldn't use `git blame` to find out who changed lines. Things like moving/renaming files, fixing indentation, etc, will show the "wrong"
 person as the author of the line in question. In my experience on large projects `git blame` is wrong most of the time.

The most effective method I've found to find the "right" author of a change (someone who wrote the code / changed its logic, not a cosmetic one), is to run at the command line:

```
git log -p -- path/to/file
```

- `-p` *patch* show the changes to the file for each commit
- `--` *file* (note space before and after) only for specified file

Then search the output (using `/`, enter the pattern, then press `n` to jump to the next match) for part of the line in question. Then you can scroll up to see the commit and the author you're looking for.